# FileInputStream error in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, fileinputstream

I have moved some code from a normal method to an AsyncTask doInBackground method, and everything is working ok except the filereader. I am getting "context cannot be resolved".
I have tried taking "context.getApplicationContext()" out altogether but that just gets me "The method openFileInput(String) is undefined for the type AlarmReceiver.backgroundputFTP". Any ideas anyone please?

```
public void putFTP(Context context)
     {
         new backgroundputFTP().execute();  
     }

  private class backgroundputFTP extends AsyncTask< Void, Void,Void >
  {  

        @Override  
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
        {  
     //
 // Push query result text file to FTP server
 //

  FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
  FileInputStream fis = null;
  Looper.prepare(); 

  try {
      client.connect(ipAddress);
      client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
      client.login(user, pass);

      //
      // Create an InputStream of the file to be uploaded
      //
      filename = "sdcardstats.txt";
      fis = context.getApplicationContext().openFileInput(filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
fis = YourActivity.this.getContext().openFileInput(filename);
```

`YourActivity` is the `Activity` within which you have your AsyncTask

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but that results in "The method getContext() is undefined for the type AlarmReceiver"

Comment: @Kevmeister Then, define a field Context mContext in your AlarmReceiver, do mContext = context in your putFTP, first thing, and then use that mContext.openFileInput from your AsyncTask

Answer (score 0):

```
 fis = context.getApplicationContext().openFileInput(filename);
```

Where have you defined this context?  try this .

```
public Context cContext ;
public void putFTP(Context context)
     {
           cContext = context;
         new backgroundputFTP().execute();  
     }

  private class backgroundputFTP extends AsyncTask< Void, Void,Void >
  {  

        @Override  
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
        {  
     //
 // Push query result text file to FTP server
 //

  FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
  FileInputStream fis = null;
  Looper.prepare(); 

  try {
      client.connect(ipAddress);
      client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
      client.login(user, pass);

      //
      // Create an InputStream of the file to be uploaded
      //
      filename = "sdcardstats.txt";
      fis = cContext.openFileInput(filename);
```